# How to optimize the PostgreSQL query

Tags: sql, postgresql

I currently have 1,100,000 rows in the table and it will increase over time. I am running this Postgres query on my database server. It's taking approx 5 sec to execute. How can I optimize it to make it execute faster?

Query:

```sql
    select sum(cast("total_value" as float)) as "total_value", sum(cast("fob_value" as float)) as "total_fob_value"
    from export
    where ("total_value" != 'N/A' and "total_value" != 'N?A') and
          ("fob_value" != 'N/A' and "fob_value" != 'N?A') and
          "product_desc" ilike '%pen%' and 
          ("shipping_date" between '2020-07-31T13:00:00.000Z' and '2020-08-28T09:58:04.451Z');
```

Comment: You might want to store your numbers as *numbers*, and not as strings, so you don't have to continually cast them and filter out non-numeric values.

Comment: You should _definitely_ store numbers as numbers. This `'N/A'` and `'N?A'` stuff is such nonsense; that's what `null`able columns are for. Don't defer fixing the data into a proper format to the point of querying; do it before insertion. Unless you have some really good reason not to...?

Comment: Thanks @underscore_d for editing the term `lakhs`, and converting it to a 'normal' number.

Comment: @underscore_d thanks dear, but I can't change the schema as of now. I do not have permission to do so and many records were entered already. So that's the concern.

Comment: Can you at least [edit] to show the full schema of the table including column types and indexes? Else people will try to recommend adding indexes that you might already have.

Answer (score 3):

There is little that you can do *for this query*.  Two possible indexes are a standard index on `shipping_date` or a GIN/GIST index for `product_desc`.

However, you can fix your data model.  Do not store numeric values as strings.  Invalid values can be stored using `NULL`.  Also, do not use double quotes when defining column or table names.  They just clutter queries.

With those changes, the query would simplify to:

```
select sum(total_value) as total_value, sum(fob_value) as total_fob_value
from export
where product_desc ilike '%pen%' and 
      shipping_date between '2020-07-31T13:00:00.000Z' and '2020-08-28T09:58:04.451Z';
```

This won't execute much faster, but it is much simpler to read and interpret.

Comment: Right, that's how NULL should be used.